# Sepearate List for Grand Total

Tags: infopath

Is this possible where I have two lists - one is a claim form and the other is an authorisation amount. The results in the authorisation amount will contain a unique reference with a total amount that has been approved whilst the claim one will be individual claims with the refence number attached (links to the authorisation list)

What I want to do is create a third list with the unique reference (auth list) - authorisation value (auth list) - sum of all Claims (linked by unique reference - claim list)

Is that possible? if so, any ideas easiest way of doing it? I've been searching for sumifs in sharepoint but I'm a novice so any plain English guides will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar recently with a Polling mechanism.

Basically I have 2 lists, Polls and Poll Votes. What we wanted was a way to show the total number of votes for each option without exposing who voted for what exactly.

What I did was setup 2 workflows and a third list. The first workflow creates a "PollCounter" item in the third list. This tracks the individual counts for each vote option. Then whenever someone submits a vote, the second workflow runs and increments the count for the respective vote in that third list.

It involves a lot of lookup references and conditional checks, but overall it works well. Just be careful with how that third list is secured. Restrict access so that only admins or the workflow can manipulate the values in it. I would verify this under load as well, if 100 people submit a vote at the same time, the count might get skewed. In your case I'm not sure how frequently it's updated.

Another much simpler option might just be setting up a profile page with filtered "lookup" views. Using views you can create a sum of all items in a column, and that view can have a filter applied based on the "current" item whose profile you're viewing. Would that work in your case?

Comment: Sounds positive however being a novice I'd probably struggle to get the workflow route working. The lookup views may work - any idea/guides to do that? I was able to get a sum of all values using a create view on the claim submissions but it's the lookup bit that I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Simplest way I know is to open the DispForm.aspx for the "master" record (ie. the category list item). On that page open it in edit mode and add a list view webpart for the "child" list that contains the records with the amounts you want to sum. Then, set that list view to be filtered by the parent webpart (ie. the category item). Hope that helps...

Comment: so I'm still trying to get this to work I came across this - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/687644/webcontrols?pageflow=fixedwidth - but not sure if this would work? any other ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: That looks about right. It's essentially the same thing I suggested in my first solution. Basically whenever something is created it increments the running total in a separate list. Still, you can probably just create a view, group by the unique key, and add a SUM to the value column.

Comment: thanks Chad - but if I create a view from it can I use that data in another library/list? I didn't think it was possible to pull information from summed views?

Comment: No the SUM in a view is display only, it's calculated dynamically on each page load. If you need to store and reference the values, you can either programmatically calculate it each time you need it, or keep a running total in a separate list as I outlined earlier.